# Как собрать в html приложение на react+next js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hook, nextjs

Изучаю next js, хочу сделать билд. Делаю npm run build, запустилась команда next build. Но в файлах появились только файлы main-fc7d2f0e2098927e вот такие, нет корневого html файлы, не понимаю, как это можно допустим залить на сервер и запустить или билд нужно делать по другому?